# In C#, what is a synchronous alternate for HttpClient.getStringAsync() method?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

In a winform, clicking on a button calls this method to download link content as string and then displays string length in a textbox. This all happens asynchronously. Is there a way to do this synchronously?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can make any task block by just taking the `.Result`:

```
string response = client.GetStringAsync(...).Result;
```

However if this is running on a UI thread you should not do that. Blocking on the UI thread is not nice. Embrace the asynchronicity.

Comment: thanks...i embrace it with all my heart...just wanted to know for testing/learning purposes...

Comment: Just one thing to think about before doing this: This changes the error-handling entirely. Instead of WebException you will only receive AggregateExceptions by design. And there seems to be some bug in httpClient that creates a generic TaskCanceledException in case of a timeout.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the method WebClient.DownloadString. This method blocks while downloading the resource.

```
string response = new WebClient().DownloadString(uri);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: "We don't recommend that you use the WebClient class for new development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 3):

RestSharp is a good open source alternative to HttpClient. It supports both sync and async requests.

https://restsharp.dev/