# unauthorized exception after removing Task code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017

I am getting the following exception after having removed Task/async code:

> {
>       "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>       "ExceptionMessage": "One or more errors occurred.",
>       "ExceptionType": "System.AggregateException",
>       "StackTrace": "   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean
>   waitCompletionNotification)\r\n   at
>   ABB.API.Customers.DynamicsCRM.Accounts.BusinessLogic.AccountService.GetAccount(String
>   query, HttpRequestHeaders headers) in F:\\TFS\\Orian360
>   Res\\ABB.API\\Dev\\Customers\\DynamicsCRM\\Accounts\\BusinessLogic\\AccountService.cs:line
>   26\r\n   at
>   ABB.API.Customers.DynamicsCRM.Accounts.Web.AccountsController.GetAccount()
>   in F:\\TFS\\Orian360
>   Res\\ABB.API\\Dev\\Customers\\DynamicsCRM\\Accounts\\Web\\Controllers\\AccountsController.cs:line
>   27\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()",
>       "InnerException": {
>           "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>           "ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred while sending the request.",
>           "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException",
>           "StackTrace": null,
>           "InnerException": {
>               "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>               "ExceptionMessage": "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.",
>               "ExceptionType": "System.Net.WebException",
>               "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult
>   ar)",
>               "InnerException": {
>                   "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>                   "ExceptionMessage": "The target principal name is incorrect",
>                   "ExceptionType": "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception",
>                   "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(Byte[] incomingBlob,
>   Boolean throwOnError, SecurityStatus& statusCode)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(String incomingBlob)\r\n
>   at System.Net.NegotiateClient.DoAuthenticate(String challenge,
>   WebRequest webRequest, ICredentials credentials, Boolean
>   preAuthenticate)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.NegotiateClient.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest
>   webRequest, ICredentials credentials)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.AuthenticationManagerDefault.Authenticate(String challenge,
>   WebRequest request, ICredentials credentials)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.AuthenticationState.AttemptAuthenticate(HttpWebRequest
>   httpWebRequest, ICredentials authInfo)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmitForAuth()\r\n   at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmit(Exception& e, Boolean&
>   disableUpload)"
>               }
>           }
>       } }

**The code in its previous state worked without issue:**

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAccount(string query)
        {

            var response = Client.Instance.GetAsync(Client.Instance.BaseAddress + query);
            var responseType = response.Result.StatusCode;
            if (responseType == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage
                {
                    StatusCode = responseType
                };
            }
            return await response;
        }
```

**I then updated it to be non-async:**

```
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAccount(string query, HttpRequestHeaders headers)
    {
        var requestUri = new Uri(Client.Instance.BaseAddress + query);
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            RequestUri = requestUri
        };

        foreach (var header in headers)
        {
            request.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
        }

        var response = Client.Instance.SendAsync(request).Result;
        return response;
    }
```

**What is causing this exception?** It seems that it would be related to async/async?

The controller is defined as follows:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("accounts({id:guid})")]
    [Route("accounts")]
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAccount()
    {
        var query = Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Split('/').Last() + Request.RequestUri.Query;
        var response = _accountService.GetAccount(query, Request.Headers);
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Since this is a synchronous method, don't you have to `await` the `SendAsync`? (haven't used Task/await/etc.. before, but that seems logical to me)...

Comment: i'm not sure, since when you call .Result, doesnt it force it to basically compute right away, making it NOT async?

Comment: No. According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138176(v=vs.118).aspx) the method does not block

Comment: UNLESS you call .Result https://stackoverflow.com/a/35831540/117700

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: you da man thanks for your help

Comment: As an aggregate exception you should also taker a look at all the inner exceptions to see what may be the issue.